# SwiftUI: ScrollView with paging scrollTargetBehavior shows end of previous page in current page

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

I’m trying to show a list of pictures in my app using `ScrollView` and `.scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)` modifier. But when swipe to next page, the view does not start at the beginning of the next image, but instead include end of last image. After a few more swipe, the previous page could even take half of the screen. Any idea what could be the issue? Thanks.

example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                LazyHStack {
                    ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { _ in
                        Image(systemName: "rectangle.slash")
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                            .border(.red)
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Screenshot, this is at page 5:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `LazyHStack` default spacing. Try this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            LazyHStack(spacing: 0) { //<- change spacing to 0
                ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { _ in
                    Image(systemName: "rectangle.slash")
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                        .border(.red)
                }
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
        }
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
    }
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: wonder if there's any default current index it provides.

Comment: To scroll at a particular index you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77464447/is-that-possible-to-scroll-a-lazyvgrid-to-show-a-particular-item-in-the-middle) @AsadullahAli